# PHP Loop: Bootstrap Slider Add div with item class every 3 item and the first one will have active

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

The current code that I have is rendering additional `div`. Can you help me how to make it right?

Every 3 items it will be inside a `div` with `item` class on it and the first item will have `active` class.

```
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

  <div class="item active">
      <div class="row">
          <?php
              $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'product',
                  'product_cat' => 'Featured',
                  'posts_per_page' => 12
              );
              $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
              if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                  $postcount = 0;
                  $i = 1;
                  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                  $postcount ++;
          ?>
          <div class="col-md-4 item-entry-index">
              <div class="car-index">
                  <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->post->ID); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <?php
              if ( $i % 3 === 0 ) {
                  echo '</div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">';
              }
          ?>
          <?php
              $i++;
              endwhile;
              } else {
                  echo __( 'No products found' );
              }
              wp_reset_postdata();
          ?>
      </div>
  </div>

</div><!--.carousel-inner-->
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code, you display 12 posts per page. When you display the 12th (the last) post (which is divided by 3), you close `.item` and `.row` divs. At the same time, you open new `.item` and `.row` divs. Just after that `while` loop ends and your last post will look like: `<div class="item"><div class="row"></div></div>`. That's where the problem comes up. So, you also need to check if the post is the last item in posts array. I extended your `if` statement like: `if ($i % 3 === 0 && $i < $args['posts_per_page']) { ... }`. I hope this will help you.

```
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">

  <div class="item active">
      <div class="row">
          <?php
              $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'product',
                  'product_cat' => 'Featured',
                  'posts_per_page' => 12
              );
              $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
              if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                  $postcount = 0;
                  $i = 1;
                  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                  $postcount ++;
          ?>
          <div class="col-md-4 item-entry-index">
              <div class="car-index">
                  <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->post->ID); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
              </div>
          </div>
          <?php
              if ( $i % 3 === 0 && $i < $args['posts_per_page']) {
                  echo '</div></div><div class="item"><div class="row">';
              }
          ?>
          <?php
              $i++;
              endwhile;
              } else {
                  echo __( 'No products found' );
              }
              wp_reset_postdata();
          ?>
      </div>
  </div>

</div><!--.carousel-inner-->
```